# Updating polygon attribute based on mode value from cluster of points using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, spatial-database

I'm updating a PostGIS table of polygons denoting property boundaries with some values that form part of a code for sites scattered across the properties. Neither dataset is 100% accurate so I can't rely on a direct attribute transfer based on overlap; instead I need to find a way to take the most common value from the points and apply them to the polygon. Attaching an image to clarify:

[image]

That image also shows an example where a polygon needs to be defined for EY-183 but that's another matter.

Any ideas on how to do this, either in PostGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mode aggregate function isn't available in PostgreSQL (<9.4) by default but you can easily [add it](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode). Once you have that, it's a simple matter of choosing the mode, grouped by polygon.

```
SELECT mode(a.name), b.gid 
FROM pt_table a INNER JOIN poly_table b
ON ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom)
GROUP BY b.gid;
```

Of course this isn't a particularly robust way of identifying polygons, but it's a start.

Comment: thanks a lot Rob! Great knowledge. It looks like the syntax has changed a bit - when I run that function the message i get is ERROR:  WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate mode. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Yes, in that link to the mode function it actually explains the syntax for the built-in mode in 9.4. More information on ordered-set aggregate functions [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE).