# Getting flow directions of people moving

Tags: postgis, algorithm

I'm creating an application which finds out the direction people are walking in, Gives the direction in which majority of people are walking and the people going in the opposite direction.

For example : 
Assume that 5 people start at 0,0. You can see the final positions in the image:
[image]

The result should be something like this
[image]

What is happening is, that we recognise that the majority of the people in this case move in the general direction 45deg to the X axis. Based on this result we calculate that the people who are walking in the opposite direction to 45deg x Axis are 2.

My output will generally be

```
{
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    angle : 45,
    flow : 3,
    antiflow : 2
}
```

I'm unable to figure out an approach to this problem.

------------EDIT-------------

As has been requested, I'm adding a few more details about the table structure.

This stuff is stored in postGIS.

The positions are all integers.

I have one table which contains data of where each person is

```
pointId|personId|position|timestamp
  1    |  1     |  0,0   |  0
  2    |  1     |  0,1   |  1
  3    |  1     |  1,0   |  2
  4    |  1     |  2,0   |  3
  5    |  2     |  0,0   |  12
  6    |  2     |  -1,-1 |  13
  7    |  2     |  -1,0  |  14
  8    |  2     |  0,0   |  15
```

Comment: What particular usecase do you have in mind ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93936)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. It isn't very clear where your data are coming from, how you are representing time steps, etc. If you could add some more details you will likely attract better answers. The question seems an interesting one.

Comment: Fx Don't let the downvote and the comment scare you from GIS.SE. This would have been a perfect question to ask as a comment.

Comment: Direction make it simpler. Blind coding isn't wise

Comment: @FxLambda So this basically helps identify which is the majority side to which people are moving and identify w.r.t. this direction how many are going in the opposite direction...

Comment: Using aggregate mode might be the best way to handle this situation if you prefer an azimuth for the resulting "flow" rather than a quadrant result  [Updating polygon attribute based on mode value from cluster of points using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167943/updating-polygon-attribute-based-on-mode-value-from-cluster-of-points-using-post)

Answer (score 1):

**Using a generic quadrant method:**

Assuming that all people start at 0,0 and you just want to assign a quadrant to a person then this is probably the simplest:

```
if endx > 0 and endy > 0 then northeast
if endx < 0 and endy > 0 then southeast
if endx > 0 and endy < 0 then northwest
if endx < 0 and endy < 0 then southwest
```

if you want to calculate a person's angle:

```
angle = inverseTan(endy/endx)
```

and angle would need to use the quadrant from above to determine how to figure the bearing:

```
angle = inverseTan(endy/endx)
if endx > 0 and endy > 0 then northeast 
    bearing = angle
if endx < 0 and endy > 0 then southeast
    bearing = angle + 90
if endx > 0 and endy < 0 then northwest
    bearing = 270 - angle
if endx < 0 and endy < 0 then southwest
    bearing = 270 + angle
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [ST_Azimuth](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html) to find the angle of each point from (0,0).

Then you can decide how to divide up your planes and tally the results for each plane.

[image]

In your example results image it looks like anything between 315 and 135 will be positive and anything else is negative.

Once you decide on a dividing line then you should be able to average the angles somehow. Not sure if the angles between 315 and 360 will throw your average off so that probably gonna take a little brain power.